# Передать данные через NavLink в Route react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

У меня есть массив навлинков через map.

```
{category.map(item =>  <NavLink 
to="/catalog/special" state={item.id} className="product__wrap" key={item.id}>
</NavLink>
 )}
```

Могу ли я передать через клик по NavLink данные в Компоненту? Компонента находится намного выше. То есть по клику нужно передавать id этого элемента и работать с ним.

```
<Route path='/catalog/special' element={<SpecialEquipCatalog h1={'Спецтехника'} types='0' />}></Route>
```

Answer (score 0):

Нашел решение, достаточно передать в NavLink данные такого типа:

```
<NavLink to={{pathname :"/catalog/special"}} 
   state={{from: item.id}} className="product__wrap" key={item.id}>
</NavLink>
```

А в компоненту передать import UseLocation и вытащить данные

```
import {useLocation} from "react-router";

const CategoryMain = props =>{
  return(
        const location = useLocation();
        const { state } = location;
        console.log(state.from);
)
}
```